# when i am going to run "rostopic echo /cmd_vel" command i get following warning

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

WARNING: topic [/cmd_vel] does not appear to be published yet

plz tell me how can i solve this warning....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73471/when-i-am-going-to-run-%22rostopic-echo-/cmd_vel%22-command-i-get-following-warning./) by [pavanpatel](https://answers.ros.org/users/5686/pavanpatel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-08-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That means that the node publishing to that topic is probably not running. Try `rostopic list`

(and follow the tutorials)

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5